# To get to a location first, is it better to leave early or wait to be over it?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

In PUBG, if the plane is going over a location you want to land at, is it better to leave early and glide your way there or wait to be over the location and go straight down?

Comment: That's really hard to test because it depends on drop time, how quickly you angle downward, your speed etc.

Comment: I would imagine the more time without your parachute the better if we're talking about getting their faster. If that's the case then there really isn't a difference in when you drop.

Comment: The in air time will be shorter with the straight down... I guess the question boils down to will the time saved by going straight down be more than the extra time you spent in the plane.

Comment: In my opinion, is better waiting to be over it and drop down with the highest velocity, because it affects in your drop discance when game opens the parachute.

Comment: @n_palum It is hard to test but it can be determined if you know a couple of variables, plane speed, plane height, and player speed at an angle vs straight down. Now where exactly you can find those stats on the net I have no idea but you could probably make some guesses with some testing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reach your landing spot the fastest you want to leave the plane about 200m before your target. Once you have left the plane hold forward and **look straight down**, this should point your character straight at the ground and have you descend at around 234 km/hr (65m/s) with very little forward movement. At around 300m from the ground your chute will open, continue holding forward, and point towards your intended landing zone. If you over shoot by a bit don't worry, as spiraling while holding forward has the same vertical speed as going straight. This means it won't affect how long it takes to hit the ground if you need to turn around last minute. On average your descent will take around 35 seconds.

Things get a little more tricky if your target isn't within 200m of the plane path, but the video below does a good job at breaking down player speeds/movement while free-falling and parachuting:

For reference here are the vertical and lateral speeds discussed in the video:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thats pretty deep in detail